# How to integrate firebase in Nrwl Nx

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, nrwl

I'd really like to integrate firebase as well as firebase cli to my apps in Nx but don't know how.  I use firebase functions/hosting/cli-tools, etc.  Ideally I'd like to be able to use the firebase cli to deploy individual apps for hosting and cloud functions, rules, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I have stumbled on the same problem and created discussion on their github repository. Feel free to join: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/836

Answer (score 2):

to work with angular & firebase, I suggest using The official Angular library for Firebase "@angular/fire".

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

--

I already successfully setup nx + angular + firebase. (ps. with only one app in nx monorepo)

details and pictures can be found here:

https://blog-host-d6b29.web.app/2022/11/27/nx-angular-fire.html

I suggest you also try to setup a new nx + angular workspace, walk through my steps and see how it works.

Comment: have you tried to run emulators with this set up.  I have a project set up the same way but cant get the emulators to work